# Writing URLs with GET variables differently

Tags: php, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide PHP from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701013/hide-php-from-user)

How do other sites manage to write their URLS without a file extension with GET variables like so:

```
http://foo.com/somepage?a=hello
```

but on my site it's always:

```
http://foo.com/somepage.php?a=hello
```

How do they drop the extension and still get it to work?

Comment: FWIW although it is true that you can achieve this via rewrite rules as shown the other question, it is also possible to do this (and much more) with a *[front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller)*. Most popular frameworks use this approach to prettify the URLs. I suggest you have a look at them (e.g. Zend or symfony).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Copy and pasting the content from another answer without referencing it is not good. You voted to close the question, why do you provide this answer then?

Comment: It's taken from my own answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701013/hide-php-from-user/6701032#6701032

Comment: :D indeed. Still. I see no point in that. Referring to the duplicate question is enough...

Comment: Every question counts and every question deserves answer, even closed

Comment: Well, does downvoter care to give me reason? Answer is correct ...

Answer (score 0):

The URL plus query string is first parsed by your server, eg Apache. So you can configure your server to map a certain URL which is sent to the server (the nice looking one) onto another more specific one regarding what file to execute in the end (the usual looking one with.php and stuff). In case of Apache this mapping is done by a module [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which can be configured to have it your way. This is done by specialized regular expressions that tell the module what to do with what part of the provided URL.

Via google you will find lots of tutorials for Apache's mod_rewrite.